# Best way to deserialize a long string (response of an external web service)

Tags: c#, json, parsing, serialization

I am querying a web service that was built by another developer.  It returns a result set in a  JSON-like format.  I get three column values (I already know what the ordinal position of each column means):

```
[["Boston","142","JJK"],["Miami","111","QLA"],["Sacramento","042","PPT"]]
```

In reality, this result set can be thousands of records long.

What's the best way to parse this string?

I guess a JSON deserializer would be nice, but what is a good one to use in C#/.NET?  I'm pretty sure the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json serializer won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built in libraries for asp.net (`System.Runtime.Serialization` and `System.ServiceModel.Web`) you can get what you want pretty easily:

```
string[][] parsed = null;
var jsonStr = @"[[""Boston"",""142"",""JJK""],[""Miami"",""111"",""QLA""],[""Sacramento"",""042"",""PPT""]]";
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonStr)))
{
    var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string[][]));
    parsed = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as string[][];
}
```

**A little more complex example (which was my original answer)**
First make a dummy class to use for serialization. It just needs one member to hold the result which should be of type string[][].

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember(Name="d")]
    public string[][] d { get; set; }
}
```

Then it's as simple as wrapping your result up like so: `{ "d": /your results/ }`. See below for an example:

```
Result parsed = null;
var jsonStr = @"[[""Boston"",""142"",""JJK""],[""Miami"",""111"",""QLA""],[""Sacramento"",""042"",""PPT""]]";
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(string.Format(@"{{ ""d"": {0} }}", jsonStr))))
{
    var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Result));
    parsed = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as Result;
}
```

Comment: THanks, your simple example worked well.  I don't need the complex stuff - but good to know.

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)?

Comment: Please don't bare-link. Include an applicable title and excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a pretty simple format that you could write a custom parser for, since you don't always want to wait for it to parse and return the entire thing before it uses it.

I would just write a recursive parser that looks for the tokens "[", ",", "\"", and "]" and does the appropriate thing.